# Proof by induction that I'm stumped on.

Tags: induction

$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}k(_k^n)=n2^{n-1}
$$

I'm trying to solve this by induction but I have no idea where to start and induction was not taught very well so I'm trying to get it cleared up in any way possible.

Comment: What did you mean? This sum $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}kC_n^k=n2^{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, that's it I wasn't able to put it into the code format.

Comment: It is not a natural for induction. The nicest argument is combinatorial. The easiest algebraic argument uses $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: I've actually edited it again so that it looks exactly as it does on the exercise.

Comment: Why is this downvoted thrice?

Comment: `{n\choose k}`.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$. Number of $k$-subsets is equal to $C_n^k$. Number of elements in $k$-subsets is equal to $kC_n^k$. Total $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}kC_n^k$.

But on the other hand, it is equal to $n2^{n-1}$ (because each $k$-set we can complete to $n$-set adding $(n-k)$ elements. After this process we have $2^n$ $n$-subsets but each set meets twice. So, $\dfrac{n2^n}{2}=n2^{n-1}$). We get $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}kC_n^k=n2^{n-1}.$
It was a combinatorial proof.

Let's go to inductional proof.

We see that for $n=1$ it's true.
Let it be true for $n-1$. Then we have $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1}kC_{n-1}^{k}=(n-1)2^{n-2}$.

Now we will prove for $n$. Here we will use this property of binomial coefficients: $C_n^k=C_{n-1}^k+C_{n-1}^{k-1}$.

$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}kC_n^k=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}kC_{n-1}^{k}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}kC_{n-1}^{k-1}=(n-1)2^{n-2}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}((k-1)+1)C_{n-1}^{k-1}=(n-1)2^{n-2}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)C_{n-1}^{k-1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}C_{n-1}^{k-1}=(n-1)2^{n-2}+(n-1)2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}=n2^{n-1}.$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: The main problem was changed slightly.

Comment: It was a combinatorial proof. Do you have a problems with inductional proof?

Answer (score 1):

Actually quite nice, if you remember your binomial coefficients, basic summation manipulation, and Pascal's identity:
$$
\binom{n + 1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1}
$$
Base: $n = 1$ is trivial

Induction: We will compute the left hand side for $n + 1$, and reach the corresponding right hand side.
\begin{align}
\sum_{1 \le k \le n + 1} k \binom{n + 1}{k}
  &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n + 1} k \left( \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1} \right) \\
  &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n + 1} k \binom{n}{k} 
       + \sum_{1 \le k \le n + 1} k \binom{n}{k - 1} \\
  &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k \binom{n}{k} 
       + \sum_{0 \le k \le n} (k + 1) \binom{n}{k} \\
  &= n 2^{n - 1}
       + 1 \cdot \binom{n}{0} 
       + \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k \binom{n}{k}
       + \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} \\
  &= n 2^{n - 1} + 1 + n 2^{n - 1} + 2^n - 1 \\
  &= (n + 1) 2^n
\end{align}
This is the claim for $n + 1$.

I didn't write down where the induction hypothesis is used (twice), and where I'm using that
$$
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} = (1 + 1)^n = 2^n
$$
The LaTeX here is sadly underpowered for this.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different track to prove the identity is to use generating functions. Note that:
$$
\sum_{1 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} z^k = (1 + z)^n - 1
$$
To get a factor $k$ multiplying the binomial coefficient, differentiate the above polynomial:
$$
z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} ((1 + z)^n - 1)
  = n z (1 + z)^{n - 1}
  = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k \binom{n}{k} z^k
$$
Evaluate at $z = 1$ to get:
$$
\sum_{1 \le k \le n} k \binom{n}{k} = n 2^{n - 1}
$$
Computing:
$$
\sum_{1 \le k \le n} k^2 \binom{n}{k}
$$
is left as an exercise.

Comment: Really, really nice!!